# html img src use <filename>?param

Tags: html, image

I have 3 different sizes for the same image.

Can I achieve something like the following:

```
<img src='/path/to/image.jpg'></img>
<img src='/path/to/image.jpg?small'></img>
<img src='/path/to/image.jpg?large'></img>
```

I have tried the above but it instead shows `image.jpg`

Comment: The `<img src="path.co.uk/to/image.png" />` element is a void element; therefore it doesn't have a closing tag; it self-closes (the `/` at the end of the tag.

Comment: Yes, you can achieve such thing. Which problem are you experiencing? What did you do on the server?

Comment: have you tried accessing the urls directly? i.e. http://youdomain.com/path/to/image.jpg?small to ensure that what you expect to happen happens?

Comment: You say you have 3 different sizes for your image. Tell us how you named them.

Comment: Come on. Tell us the names. :-)

Comment: @smartmeta I called them image.jpg, image.jpg?medium, and image.jpg?large

Comment: @rikAtee: That are realy extraordinary filenames.

Comment: I was really experimenting if there is a "nice" way to manage this task hence the file names. I have now falled back to small_image.jpg, etc

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1488280/what-are-the-legal-allowed-characters-for-web-server-file-names-on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The browser doesn't understand what you're trying to do. Why not append the size to the end of the image, like so:

```
<img src='/path/to/image.jpg></img>
<img src='/path/to/image.jpg_small></img>
<img src='/path/to/image.jpg_large></img>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to keep the same image and add some css style to each one, instead of calling the same image 3 times from it path something like:

html code

```
<div>
    <img src="/path/image.jpg" width="100" height="100">
</div>

<div id="scale-up" style="height: 230px">
    <img src="/path/image.jpg">
</div>

<div id="scale-down" style="height: 57px">
    <img src="/path/image.jpg">
```

css code

```
img {
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 100%;
}
#scale-up {
    height: 230px;
}
#scale-down {
    height: 57px;
}
```

Comment: small will be used most often (99% of the time). large is used once, medium infrequently.

Comment: most (99%) of users will only need to see the thumbnail image, so I don't want to serve a full size image to them, as this costs me bandwidth.

Comment: It won't effect your bandwidth, upload your image once and change the scale up and down how you would like it to be, also add the css to your style sheet, this way your fine!

Comment: can you prove that? If 99% of 5000 users only need a 1 kb  thumbnail and I serve them a 50 kb full size image css'd down in size then I'm incurring an extra 200 mb bandwidth.

Answer (score 0):

If you want filenames to look like (on server):

```
fd11f91bb8361030bdc09d8b8ed4f88e?w=200&h=76&f=png
```

You need to url encode them when requesting to server. For example using http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/

So url encoded file will look like:

```
fd11f91bb8361030bdc09d8b8ed4f88e%3Fw%3D200%26h%3D76%26f%3Dpng
```

So in your case it should be:

```
<img src='/path/to/image.jpg'></img>
<img src='/path/to/image.jpg%3Fsmall'></img>
<img src='/path/to/image.jpg%3Flarge'></img>
```

Answer (score 0):

Like @Leo mentioned, using html-tags (or css) is much easier here than a url-based approach. (which would require server logic)

The html-tag resizing would look like:

```
<img src="/path/to/image.jpg" width="100" height="100">
```

You mention that you dislike how that might increase the bandwidth usage. This shouldn't be a problem as long as your website uses caching on the images. (it will only download the image once then, and just resize the same image locally for the different  tags)

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest

```
<img src="/path/to/image.jpg"></img>
<img src="/path/to/image_small.jpg"></img>
<img src="/path/to/image_large.jpg"></img>
```

to keep the file extension.